# How to change datagrid cell value when user leaves cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

Can't find any way to do what i what.
I have a `DataGridView` named `data1`. All i want is to check if  current cell is acceptable(not lower than `-99`) after we fill it. And if it is - change it to `-99`. Similar if i set minimum to a textbox and change its value if it's not correct.
Here is the code:

```
private void data1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.Value) < -99)
    {
        ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.Value = -99;                
    }
}
```

This code does not work. And no errors appeared.

Comment: Please explain what is the error received, if any

Comment: No errors. It's just not working when i change a value in a cell and leave.

Comment: [MSDN on CellLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellleave%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) _Occurs when a cell loses input focus and is no longer the current cell._ So you need to keep a reference to the previously current cell..! Or better as in stuart's answer: user the e4.Params!

Comment: @OhBeWise thanks for the tip, I will do it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works as you want it to:

```
private void data1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)data1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value) <= -99)
        cell.Value = -99;
}
```

`Cellleave` Event gets previous value of the cell after you have changed it to a different one and left the cell. And `CellEndEdit` Event gets the last value. The code works **the same** also in `CellValidated` Event.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [DataGridView.CellValidating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) this event fires when the user is leaving the current cell but before CellLeave fires or bound data gets pushed to the datasource. This allows you to: check the value the user entered, prevent the user from leaving the cell, change the value the user entered, set an error indicator on the cell.

Comment: That is not working with this code. This one works: [DataGridView.CellValidated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx)